# Why doesn't an input modify a value outside of an ng-repeat (and ng-switch)?

Tags: angularjs

I am assuming a scope problem is the reason the input in this example can modify the value next to it, but not the other value.  If this is the case, how do I hook up the model to right scope?  If it isn't a scope problem, what am I doing wrong?

```
<html ng-app>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="angular-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function ExampleCtrl($scope) {
                $scope.list = [
                    { name: "a" },
                    { name: "b" },
                ];

                $scope.value = 5;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="ExampleCtrl">
        <ul ng-repeat="item in list">
            <li>{{ item.name }}
                <ng-switch on="item.name">
                    <span ng-switch-when="b">
                        <input type="number" ng-model="value" />
                        {{ value }}
                    </span>
                </ng-switch>
            </li>
        </ul>

        value is {{ value }}
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another way - you can access parent scope using $parent.

```
<input type="number" ng-model="$parent.$parent.value" />
```

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/7Hh2R/

Comment: By the way, where is `$parent` documented?  I can't seem to find it one the website.

Comment: @Chas.Owens I can't find documentation on $parent. I know it from mailing list. It is defined [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/54e4a6ffbf9de21d33bc9f770db93677590d148a/src/ng/rootScope.js#L197).

And I know at least one more undocumented thing - [ngValue directive](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/f16150d5f1b20b3d633b4402095ea89baa4be042/src/ng/directive/input.js#L1235)

Comment: Actually, using $parent is kind of hack. I advice you to introduce model object (kind of ```$scope.editngItem = { value: '' };``` and reference field of that model object: ``ng-model='editingItem.value'```. This is more nicer way.

Comment: Documentation states: "This directive creates new scope".  For a newbie its not clear what the implications of this are. But this answer certainly helps.

Answer (score 5):

You're right both [ngRepeat](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angRepeat) and [ngSwitch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSwitch) create different scopes. You can use the awesome [AngularJS Batarang](https://github.com/angular/angularjs-batarang) developer tool for Chrome to see the different scopes in action.

One change you can make to reference the same value in your code is to reference an object property instead of a primitive type like:

```
$scope.value = { val: 5 };
```

and bind to:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="value.val"/>
{{ value.val }}
```

I'll be interested to see if there are better ways to handle this with the different scopes.

Comment: Well, that works, but I really hope there is a better solution.